# Link Pages in OnesenUI without toolbar

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui2

I'm new to OnesenUI. I have been able to use the  tag to link pages using the toolbar. However, I would want to know how do I link a text in the page to another screen.

e.g. if I have text "Register" then, the user should be able to go the register.html screen.

I don't want to have a toolbar button for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

login.html Code:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input id="emaillogin" type="text" placeholder="email" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input id="passwordlogin" type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:Login();" class="btn btn-template-outlined"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log in</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="center" style="text-align: center">
<p><br>If you are not enrolled, you can sign-up now.</p>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<button type="button" href="register.html" class="btn btn-template-outlined"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Show some code effort

Comment: @CodeBlooded any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you use `a` tag directly?

Comment: @CodeBlooded tried doing that but it doesn't work.